# iOS Voip wakeup call

Tags: c++, ios, qt, sockets

I have an application that is a socket server application. I want to use it on iOS (not app store). I have tried to bind my C++ program's native socket the way it is mentioned in the apple documentation, however nothing is happening.

The C++ program is using signal/slots with QTcpServer. I have some code like this:

```
driver = ProxyDriver::getInstance(5150);
    NSLog(@"Socket descriptor %i" , driver->socketDescriptor());
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket (kCFAllocatorDefault, driver->socketDescriptor(),  &readStream, &writeStream);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
```

driver->socketDescriptor() returns the int that is my QTcpServer's listening socket.

The code I posted is in my app delegates "applicationDidEnterBackground" and I have enabled "Voice over IP" in my .plist file.

However, it seems weird - if I do a netcat to the IP address of the listening socket while the application is in the background - it does not wake up and call the "accept connections" slot that I have defined in my Qt app. However, as soon as I bring the app back to the foreground, the slot is called.

What am I doing wrong? Do I already need to have a socket connected before I can create my stream pair?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the socket need to be connected to server before the App going to background, otherwise iOS won't keep it "alive"

You can not use a listening socket for the VOIP Background functionality.